# Can't assign property: Unexpected . (dot) Expected end-of-statement

Tags: lotusscript

Newbie to LotusScript here, so please be gentle ;)

Why does this code give me the error `Unexpected: .; Expected: End-of-statement` ?

```
Dim curDate As New NotesDateTime(Today)
Dim test
Set test = Day(curDate).DateOnly   ' <- causes the error
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write

```
Set test = Day(curDate.DateOnly)
```

because `DateOnly` is a property of curDate.